# How likely is it to get into grad school with many W's and an F on your transcript given you have medical documents that give reason for your grades?

Tags: career-path, computer-science, science

I currently have a 3.47 GPA at Georgia Tech in Computer Science. I have already withdrew from 6 classes but 4 of those were from a semester I got hospitalized. I'm failing a class right now but I may be able to pull of a C or even an A because the final replaces the course grade.

I want to do a Master's in environmental science or environmental modeling. I want to be a data scientist for the NOAA or any organization working on the acidification of the ocean.

I may even do a PhD if I can. I have research experience.

Comment: "How likely" is one of those opinion questions; how should we know. "What can I do about...?" might be better, but it's also opinion.  *Ask someone* at GaTech what you have to do to get into the program you want.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll go through our earth science department.